# Absolutely positioned overlay ignores z-index

Tags: html, position, overlay, z-index

I have the following template that I am trying to get working, I have taken the liberty to add different color backgrounds to each div for debugging, basically I have three divs that are different backgrounds and these backgrounds need to have a glow in the center.  To do this I tried setting an absolutely positioned container with 10% opacity.  However it overlays everything and ignores z-index.

I know I am missing something simple, but I have been looking at this for too long.

http://fwuse.com/n/ No glow, the colors are not the design they are their for debugging.
http://fwuse.com/n/glow.html Glow container added, only the menu sticks out, everything else is hidden.
http://fwuse.com/n/glow-opacity.html Glow container with opacity, notice none of the links can be clicked.

Comment: works fine in chrome. what browser are you struggling with?

Comment: What is the end result supposed to be?

Comment: @AlienWebguy Chrome 12.0.742.122

Comment: looks like it's working to me O_o 12.0.742.122

Comment: @thirtydot three backgrounds with a centered 960px container @ 10% opacity over the backgrounds and the content on top

Comment: @Joseph, it isn't though the white container on the second page is covering up all the content.

Comment: your bgs are z-index of 1 and your glow is index of 2. It covers them, but because your bgs are index of 1, their child nodes are also at that level.  Thus your content is covered.

Comment: I still don't understand what the end result should be :(

Comment: The problem seems to exist at least on OS X Safari 5.0.5.

Comment: @Joseph I want the glow to cover the backgrounds, however I do not want any of the child nodes to be covered.  How would I do that?

Comment: @Kaivosukeltaja the behavior is cross browser actually, it looks the same in Chrome, Firefox and IE, which is odd, you would think at least one would give a different result.

Comment: @thirtydot look at the last page, it should look like that, except the glow needs to not overlay the child elements, because it does you can not click any links, except the menu for some reason.

Comment: @Sean I honestly don't know... I can imagine that if it's cosmetic there's probably a simpler way though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can make the content div not have a background color(background:transparent ?) and have z-index 3, and the underlying "10% opacity" div have z-index 2, it will work. I am not sure if background:transparent is a property in CSS however ;)

Comment: I did as you suggested, didn't make a difference the a tags are still unclickable =( http://fwuse.com/n/glow-opacity.html thanks for trying.

Comment: @Sean : Which a tags? The aqua blue ones?

Comment: it covers up everything, the Login tag in the Indigo box, the links in the Aqua blue box, links in the content box, and the footer links.

Comment: Just checked your stylesheet. Your z-indexes are still bad. Give all that you want to place on top of the 10% opacity div(which will have z-index 2), z-index 3. Remember also that z-index will work only for absolutely positioned elements.

Comment: I updated all the child nodes to be z-index: 3 and the bg divs to be z-index: 2, which makes the a tags clickable again, but the glow goes behind the bgs now, if I move the glow to after the bgs in the source, I get the result I want, but the a tags are covered again =(

Comment: :) Why did you have to give the bg divs z-index 2? They are your primary layer. If at all u assign a z-index assign 1. The glow should have the z-index 2, since its your second layer, and all your content should have z-index 3 . See if it works that way :)

Comment: I changed the bg divs to 1 and now we are back to the original behavior =(

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use CSS for your glow?

```
#radial-center {
  /* fallback */
  background-color: #2F2727;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

  /* Safari 4-5, Chrome 1-9 */
  /* Can't specify a percentage size? Laaaaaame. */
  background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 460, from(#1a82f7), to(#2F2727));

  /* Safari 5.1+, Chrome 10+ */
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, #1a82f7, #2F2727);

  /* Firefox 3.6+ */ 
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(circle, #1a82f7, #2F2727);

  /* IE 10 */ 
  background: -ms-radial-gradient(circle, #1a82f7, #2F2727);

  /* IE < 8 Linear gradient fallback */
  filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#1a82f7, endColorstr=#2F2727, GradientType=1)";

  /* IE 8/9 Linear gradient fallback */
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#1a82f7, endColorstr=#2F2727, GradientType=1)";
  /* Opera cannot do radial gradients yet */

}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/49d5g/

Comment: +1 @AlienWebguy This will help with the making the logo glow for this project.

Answer (score 0):

`#content-bg` has a lower z-index than the glow which is covering the whole page, therefore consuming all the clicks for the content. Changing the z-index for `#content-bg` to 3 seemed to bring it to the front enough to be clicked while not affecting the glow effect.

Comment: @Kaviosukeltaja I have done this, but now the backgrounds are above the glow, it is close though.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, I had to set the #pagecontainer z-index and set the background divs to z-index:auto. I set header to z-index: 501, content to z-index: 502 and footer to z-index 503, #glow was set to z-index: 1.

As confusing as this is, it works, any idea why?

http://fwuse.com/no/